# Codificación UTF8 en Flutter / Darts

Tags: flutter, dart, utf-8, http-post

Tengo un problema con un Map en dart. Necesito convertir la respuesta que me viene de una petición POST a UTF8, pero no hay forma. Os pongo el código

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> login(String email, String password) async {

    final authData = {
      'user' : email,
      'pass'  : password,
      'token' : '0ab6a7687b0aa1ca3288c1bef0b79b38'
    };

    final resp = await http.post(
      'https://app1.witimsport.es/controllers/login/login.php',
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "charset": "UTF-8"},
      body: jsonEncode(authData)
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> decodedResp = json.decode(resp.body);
    
if (decodedResp['result'] == '200') {

      Map<String, dynamic> decodedResp2 = json.decode(decodedResp['data'][0]);
      
      _prefs.token  = decodedResp2['token'];
      _prefs.mail   = decodedResp2['mail'];
                  
      return {'ok':true, 'token': decodedResp2['token']};

    } else if(decodedResp['result'] == '499') {

      return {'ok': false, 'mensaje': 'Error inesperado'};

    } else {
      
      return {'ok': false, 'mensaje':  decodedResp['descripcion']};
    }

  }
```

Como véis, tengo un Map>String, dynamic>> y necesito que los datos que me vienen ahí como ut8_encode() desde PHP, pueda hacerles un utf8.decode()

Answer (score 0):

Sencillo, primero no te olvides de importar `dart:convert`.

Y luego con el `Utf8Decoder` puedes obtener la codificación correcta.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';


String stringResponse = const Utf8Decoder().convert(resp.body.codeUnits);
Map<String, dynamic> decodedResp = jsonDecode(stringResponse);
```

Comment: la solución que me comentas no me función, o al menos no del todo. Me indica el siguiente error:

**The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'**

Imagino que tiene que ver en que la función es un `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>`

Comment: en lugar de json.decode usa `jsonDecode`